# COLOR_ATTACHMENTn as a sampler input to fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, glfw, glew

I'm working on a code that requires that I send 2+ textures into a fragment shader, and then I need to get 2 COLOR_ATTACHMETn's out of the shader. Once I get `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and `COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` out from my shader is it possible to send them as samplers into an shader to be render on screen on a quad?

The reason why I need to send the COLOR_ATTACHMENTs to a second shader is that I am rendering `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and `COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` on different monitors. `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` will appear on one screen and `COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` on another...

I am running psychological experiments testing vision. My first shader does the processing of my original set of textures, but since so much of the processing required for the two output textures is the same I didn't want to have to run the shader basically twice if I don't have to.

I'm using GLFW, GLEW and GLM. So any solution using those libraries would be ideal

#### Basic vertex shader to pass texture coords and screen position

```
const GLchar* vertexSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "in vec2 texcoord;"
    "out vec2 Texcoord;"
    "void main() {"
    "   Texcoord = texcoord;"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";
```

#### Arbitrary fragment shader that takes in two samplers and puts out two vec4 "textures"

```
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 Texcoord;"
    "out vec4 outColor0;"
    "out vec4 outColor1;"
    "uniform sampler2D texLite;"
    "uniform sampler2D texDark;"
    "void main() {"
    "   outColor0 = texture(texLite, Texcoord);"
    "   outColor1 = texture(texDark, Texcoord);"
    "}";
```

#### (Same as before) Basic vertex shader to pass texture coords and screen position

```
const GLchar* vertexSourceDisp =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "in vec2 texcoord;"
    "out vec2 Texcoord;"
    "void main() {"
    "   Texcoord = texcoord;"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";
```

#### Simple fragment shader to take in sampler and display on quad

```
const GLchar* fragmentSourceDisp =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 Texcoord;"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "uniform sampler2D tex;"
    "void main() {"
    "   outColor = texture(tex, Texcoord);"
    "}";
```

When I run `glFramebufferTexture2D` it attaches a texture image to a frame buffer, so when the shader is ran is the vec4 output by my shader stored back in the texture as well as the color attachment?

## Full Code

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

// Simple through-put vertex shader
const GLchar* vertexSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "in vec2 texcoord;"
    "out vec2 Texcoord;"
    "void main() {"
    "   Texcoord = texcoord;"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";

// Basic fragment shader for the moment 
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 Texcoord;"
    "out vec4 outColor0;"
    "out vec4 outColor1;"
    "uniform sampler2D texLite;"
    "uniform sampler2D texDark;"
    "void main() {"
    "   vec4 colLena = texture(texLite, Texcoord);"
    "   vec4 colTex7 = texture(texDark, Texcoord);"
    "   outColor0 = mix(colLena, colTex7, 0.0);"
    "   outColor1 = mix(colLena, colTex7, 1.0);"
    "}";

const GLchar* vertexSourceDisp =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "in vec2 texcoord;"
    "out vec2 Texcoord;"
    "void main() {"
    "   Texcoord = texcoord;"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";

const GLchar* fragmentSourceDisp =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 Texcoord;"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "uniform sampler2D tex;"
    "void main() {"
    "   outColor = texture(tex, Texcoord);"
    "}";

    void printShaderInfoLog(GLuint obj)
{
    int infologLength = 0;
    int charsWritten  = 0;
    char *infoLog;

    glGetShaderiv(obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&infologLength);

    if (infologLength > 0)
    {
        infoLog = (char *)malloc(infologLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(obj, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog);
        printf("%s\n",infoLog);
        free(infoLog);
    }
}

void printProgramInfoLog(GLuint obj)
{
    int infologLength = 0;
    int charsWritten  = 0;
    char *infoLog;

    glGetProgramiv(obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&infologLength);

    if (infologLength > 0)
    {
        infoLog = (char *)malloc(infologLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(obj, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog);
        printf("%s\n",infoLog);
        free(infoLog);
    }
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

int main()
{
    if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int count;
    GLFWmonitor** monitors = glfwGetMonitors(&count);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window0;
    GLFWwindow* window1;

    window0 = glfwCreateWindow(1680, 1050, "OpenGL", monitors[2], window1); // Front Screen
    window1 = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 800, "OpenGL", monitors[1], window0); // Back Screen

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window0);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window0, key_callback);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

     // Vertex array object - Contains all vertex information
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Vertex buffer object
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

    // Vertices to use inside my shader
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    // Attached vertices to my GPU
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Element buffer object - allows me to reuse vertices
    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    // Index into the rows of vertices to use different vertices more than once
    GLuint elements[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    // Attach element array to use on GPU
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Set up shader
    // Vertex Shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    printShaderInfoLog(vertexShader);

    // Fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    printShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader);

    // Shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor0");
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 1, "outColor1");
    printProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(float), 0);

    GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                            4*sizeof(float), (void*)(2*sizeof(float)));

    cv::VideoCapture cap("movie.mov");
    cv::Mat image0;
    cv::Mat image1;
    int width = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int height = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    // float ratio = width/(float)height;

    //Set up samplers
    GLuint ldrTextures[2];
    glGenTextures(2, ldrTextures);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ldrTextures[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
                    GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "texLite"), 0);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);  

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ldrTextures[1]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
                    GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "texDark"), 1);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 

    //Set up framebuffer
    GLuint frameBuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

    //Set up target textures
    GLuint dispTextures[2];
    glGenTextures(2, dispTextures);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dispTextures[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
                    GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, dispTextures[0], 0);  

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dispTextures[1]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
                    GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, dispTextures[1], 0);

    GLenum bufs[2] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
    glDrawBuffers(2, bufs);

    bool success;

    //Render loop
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window0) && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window1))
    {
        std::cout << "Loop" << std::endl;

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Grab two frames from video
        success = cap.read(image0);

        if(!success)
        {
            std::cout << "Could not grab a frame" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }

        success = cap.read(image1);

        if(!success)
        {
            std::cout << "Could not grab a frame" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ldrTextures[0]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
                    GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image0.data);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ldrTextures[1]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
                    GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1.data);

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window0);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window0, key_callback);

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

        // glViewport(0,0,width,height);

        // glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window0);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window0, key_callback);

        glViewport(0,0,width,height);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dispTextures[0]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window0);
        glfwPollEvents();

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window1);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window1, key_callback);

        glViewport(0,0,width,height);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, dispTextures[1]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window1);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    //Clean up memory, remember good coding practices
    glDeleteTextures(1, ldrTextures);
    glDeleteTextures(1, dispTextures);

    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    glfwTerminate();

}
```

Comment: `texLite` and `texDark` are my original two images. Im am reading them in with OpenCv and converting them to textures then using them in the shader as samplers. I need to get `outColor0` and `outColor1` as two new textures every time I call `glUseProgram`. Is there a way to take my color attachments and turn them back into textures?

Comment: @Maggic: you can render to textures, so your color attachments can be textures. But I really don't get the point of all of this. What problem are you even trying to solve here?

Comment: I have two displays (two different monitors) I want to run one shader that processes a series of images/textures, then from that shader I need to return two images/textures/color_attachments. Each of the color attachments needs to rendered onto a quad on a different screen. I am unable to render onto both screens for some reason. But I was trying to see if I could turn the color attachments back into textures and use a new shader to display each texture on each a different monitor. I have attached full code if it helps to understand

Comment: This is starting to sound more like an issue with multiple render contexts and resource sharing to be honest. Are you trying to drive each of these monitors using a separate window? By default the render context for each window will not share the same set of resource names, so that could be your problem.

Comment: Yes. But I have set the two windows to share resources. `GLFWwindow* window0;`
    `GLFWwindow* window1;`

    `window0 = glfwCreateWindow(1680, 1050, "OpenGL", monitors[2], window1); // Front Screen`
    `window1 = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 800, "OpenGL", monitors[1], window0); // Back Screen
`

Comment: The other problem is that you will need to synchronize the command execution in your two windows. The pipelines can run commands out-of-order with respect to one another, so that window 2 might be trying to draw using a texture before window 1 finishes writing it. A fence sync object or `glFinish (...)` may be necessary to rectify that.

Comment: I would add the `glFinish()` call right before `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window1);`. Fence syncs will give you much better performance, but the easiest way to see if this is in fact your problem is to start with `glFinish` ;) Also keep in mind each window has its own state machine, so you should really be binding `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ldrTextures[0]);` ***after*** setting window0 to active for consistency.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman how would I go about binding a `color_attachment` to `glDrawElements`? This does not seem to be working?

Comment: So after I run my shader I have two color attachments. How would I go about taking just one of the color attachments and placing it on a quad so it appears on screen? I've tried unbinding my color attachments from the fob, does that return them to the texture in memory? Then How do I display that single color attachment when I call `glDrawElements`

Comment: Bind the texture that corresponds to that color attachment. That's all you have to do. I think there is some fundamental misunderstanding about FBOs here. You attach images to FBO attachment points, those images can be Render Buffers or Textures and the only special consideration is that you cannot sample from a texture while it is attached to the currently active FBO (undefined results). Try taking two windows out of the equation first, because that introduces some complications that I'm not sure we have eliminated (such as making sure window 0 finishes writing before window 1 reads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code only shows a single GLSL shader program being compiled and linked. You should have two different programs here, one for the first pass and another for the second (missing).

Once you get that problem sorted out, you are going to need to set the samplers accordingly. Judging by the code for your first window (`window0`) it would use sampler `tex` = **2**. The second window (`window1`) would use `tex` = **3**. Now, this is actually completely unnecessary if you understand that each render context in OpenGL has its own state machine (in other words, the texture binding state is not shared across your two windows). You can bind the texture each window uses to **2** on both render contexts and then never have to set the value of the `tex` sampler uniform to anything other than **2**.

What is necessary, and what really bothers me here, is that you are trying to use the output from one render context as the input to another with no synchronization. Render contexts in OpenGL are not synchronized, there is no guarantee that the commands from the first pass that you do in `window0` are going to be complete by the time `window1` tries to read from its output image. The easiest fix is to add a call to `glFinish ()` before you switch from `window0` to `window1`, that will cause OpenGL to block up until all of those commands finish. It is not the most performant solution (a fence sync would be better), but it is the simplest.